# R Code with minted, "¡-" instead of "<-" and underscores are omitted

Tags: overleaf, minted, r

I am using overleaf to write a LaTeX document. I want to include some R code blocks with minted, but minted displays my arrows in the code "<-" like this: "¡-". How can I fix this? I encoded both the code and my LaTeX document in utf8. It also omits underscore symbols "_" and brackets "{}.

It does not work if I include the code directly

```
\begin{minted}[linenos,breaklines,bgcolor=myLightGray]{r}
check_create_dir <- function(path) {
    print("using existing folder")
}
\end{minted}
```

And if I load a file:

```
\inputminted[linenos,breaklines,bgcolor=myLightGray]{R}{code/test.R}
```

[image: pdf output image]

Comment: Does `\usepckage[T1]{fontenc}` in the LaTeX preamble help?

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! @Rmano

Comment: Put the R code between  one line with `<<eval=F>>=` and other line with `@` and save the file with the` .Rtex` extension  (in Overleaf) or .Rnw (using Rstudio).