# Underscore visible a prime symbols when used in minted package code

Tags: minted

I am trying to include a Matlab code in a latex document. The package minted works well for this purpose despite one quirk: the variables and function containing underscore symbol "_" do not display correctly (but as "'" symbol). For example, following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{gray}{.9}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos=false,tabsize=2,breaklines,bgcolor=bg]{matlab}
Test characters with underscore like this: word_underscore.
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

results in:
[image]

Is there a way out this of issue? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: if I add `\documentclass{article}` I get undefined color `bg` error

Comment: I defined bg (added above) but then get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fArcm.png)

Comment: I think the issue is solved, as the default text encoding in my document didn't have the underscore character. Added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to preamble, now displaying properly!

Comment: that is why you should always provide a test file no one can fix code that you do not show. I tested the default OT1 encoding (as I suspeced that was the issue) but got the output shown, what encoding were you using?

Comment: Very similar to question [overleaf - R Code with minted, "¡-" instead of "<-" and underscores are omitted - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594528/r-code-with-minted-instead-of-and-underscores-are-omitted?noredirect=1&lq=1)